# Alternative ways to close HTML5 video-player

Tags: javascript, html5-video, video-player

I heard there is no way to close HTML5 video-player. So I wrote an alternative way. With the following code, double click on any character of these sentences, a video will start playback from a fixed temporal position (100 sec) at the spatial position where you would double-click. Next, press any key to stop the video and erase the video player.

[image]

But this way uses window-refresh (window.location.reload()) and so isn't gentle for eyes. I wonder if there are alternatives gentle for eyes.

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <style>
            video {
                display: none;
                position: fixed;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <video></video>
        <li>Double click on any character of these sentences.</li>
        <li>A video will start playback from a fixed temporal position (100 sec)
        <li>at the spatial position where you would double-click.</li>
        <li>Next, press any key to stop the video and erase the video player.</li>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e) => {
                //PLAYBACK VIDEO
                document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('dblclick', (e) => {
                    const video = document.querySelector('video');
                    video.controls = true;
                    video.width = "200";
                    video.autoplay = true;
                    video.src="https://archive.org/download/BigBuckBunny_328/BigBuckBunny.ogv#t=100";
                    video.style.display = 'block';
                    video.style.left = e.clientX + 'px';
                    video.style.top = e.clientY + 'px';
                });
                // CLOSE PLAYER
                document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('keypress', (e) => {
                    window.location.reload();//<<--- LOOK AT THIS!!!
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can remove the video element from the DOM, you could resize it, you could move it off-screen, you could set it's visibility or display elements.

Comment: Hi @Offbeatmammal Thank you for your comment. I appreciate your answer, but I cannot understand it. If you give a simplified explanation, that would be great for me.Thank you for your comment again.